# Laravel - must be of the type array, none given

Tags: arrays, database, laravel, posting

Having a strange problem with my laravel 5.2 build, I'm trying to send data from a form to my database and for some reason an error keeps being thrown on submit which states "Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::postStatus() must be of the type array, none given" and I'm not sure why as I am sending data into an array. My code is shown below.

timeline.blade.php
    @extends('layouts.app')

```
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="row notifications-section">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">option 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">option 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">option 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
             <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/home') }}" class="facebook-share-box">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="share">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="{{ Auth::user()->firstName }} {{ Auth::user()->lastName }}">
                                <textarea name="body" cols="40" rows="10" id="status_message" value="{{ old('body') }}" class="form-control message" style="height: 62px; overflow: hidden;" placeholder="What's on your mind ?"></textarea> 
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon icon-map-marker"></i> Location</button>
                                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon icon-picture" ></i> Photo</button>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <select name="visibility" class="form-control privacy-dropdown pull-left input-sm" value="{{ old('visibility') }}">
                                                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Public</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Only my friends</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Only me</option>
                                                </select> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-3">                                  
                                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>                              
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 profile-section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h2>{{ Auth::user()->firstName }} {{ Auth::user()->lastName }}</h2>
                    <h4>{{ Auth::user()->currentLocation }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ Auth::user()->bio }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 connect-section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">Section</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Section</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Section</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 posts-section">
            <div class="row">
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h2>{{ $post->user_name }}</h2>
                        {{ $post->created_at }}<br />
                        {{ $post->body }}
                        {{ $post->visibility }}<br />
                        <div class="row like_comment_share">
                            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#">Like</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#">Comment</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#">Share</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 @endforeach
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 @endsection
```

PostController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Posts;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class PostsController extends BaseController {

/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return Response
*/
public function index()
{

}

public function display()
{

return view('users/timeline')
        ->with('user_name', 'body', 'photo', 'visibility', 'created_at')
        ->with('posts', Posts::all());

}

/**
* Show the form for creating a new resource.
*
* @return Response
*/
protected function postStatus(array $data)
{
    return Posts::create([
        'user_name' => $data['user_name'],
        'body' => $data['body'],
        'photo' => $data['photo'],
        'visibility' => $data['visibility'],
    ]);
}
```

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_name', 'body', 'photo', 'visibility', 'created_at',
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No data is passed to the controller when you post to a route.  Instead, you access the data through the `Request` object by injecting it into the method, or by using the `Request::` or `Input::` facades.

```
protected function postStatus(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->all();

    return Posts::create([
        'user_name' => $data['user_name'],
        'body' => $data['body'],
        'photo' => $data['photo'],
        'visibility' => $data['visibility'],
    ]);
}
```