# Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

i am trying to post title and article in laravel rest api i am getting this error

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type
>   array, null given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelProject\cpapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php
>   on line 1440

This is my route/api.php file of post article data

```
Route::post('articles', 'ArticleController@store');

Route::post('articles', function(Request $request) {
   return Article::create($request->all);
});
```

And this store function of  ArticleController.php file

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $article = Article::create($request->all());

        return response()->json($article, 201);
    }
```

This is article model class

```
class Article extends Model
{
    //new
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];
}
```

i tried change this in articlecontroller file but getting same error

```
$article = Article::create($request->only([
            'title',
            'body']));
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: On a answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059864/laravel-type-error-argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-database-eloquent-modelsav   the `save()` method is used without ant params and worked, did u try use your `create()` without any params?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - must be of the type array, none given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579268/laravel-must-be-of-the-type-array-none-given)

Comment: i changed it like this $data = $request->all();
        
        $article = Article::create([
                'title' => $data['title'],
                'body' => $data['body'],
            ]);

        return response()->json($article, 201); but i still getting same error

Comment: Thanks @MasivuyeCokile i solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As #Masivuye_Cokile suggested me, i modified my code in route and controller function and it fixed my problem.

Route/api.php

```
Route::post('articles', function(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->all();
        return Article::create([
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'body' => $data['body'],
        ]);
});
```

In Controller function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $article = Article::save();
       return response()->json($article, 201);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know there's an accepted answer already, but I don't think the reason for the error was clearly explained.

If you take a look at your code below, you'll notice there's an error on the second route definition as you typed; `$request->all` instead of `$request->all()`

```
Route::post('articles', 'ArticleController@store');

Route::post('articles', function(Request $request) {
   return Article::create($request->all);
});
```

So, I think a simpler solution would be:

```
Route::post('articles', 'ArticleController@store');

Route::post('articles', function(Request $request) {
   return Article::create($request->all());
});
```