# Laravel - firstOrCreate() detects argument 1 as non-array, but it is

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have the following code:

```
$coretable = new coretable;
$coretableKeyArray = [];
$coretableKeyArray["Internal_key"] = $coretableInput["Internal_key"];
if(is_array($coretableKeyArray)){
  log::info("recognized as array");
}
$lastInsert = $coretable->firstOrCreate($coretableKeyArray, $coretableInput);
```

The array for argument 1 of `firstOrCreate()` looks like this:

```
[2020-02-27 07:30:50] local.INFO: array (
  'Internal_key' => 'TESTKEY_4',
)
```

the `is_array()` also returns true on `$coretableKeyArray`

However, when doing the call to `firstOrCreate()` here:

```
$lastInsert = $coretable->firstOrCreate($coretableKeyArray, $coretableInput);
```

I get this error:

```
 (1/1) TypeError

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::firstOrCreate() must be of the type array, int given, called in E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23
in Builder.php line 415
at Builder->firstOrCreate(4, array('coretable_id' => 4, 'description_itc' => 'EXTENSION_ITC_4'))in ForwardsCalls.php line 23
at Model->forwardCallTo(object(Builder), 'firstOrCreate', array(4, array('coretable_id' => 4, 'description_itc' => 'EXTENSION_ITC_4')))in Model.php line 1618
at Model->__call('firstOrCreate', array(4, array('coretable_id' => 4, 'description_itc' => 'EXTENSION_ITC_4')))in modelInteractions.php line 128
```

Why is that? Also, why does the log of the error show me:

```
Builder->firstOrCreate(4, array('coretable_id' => 4, 'description_itc' => 'EXTENSION_ITC_4'))
```

Why is the first argument "4" here? What does it represent? Because it cant represent the value of the first argument of the call to `firstOrCreate()` because that was an entirely different one...

EDIT:

Here is the full errorstack, as requested per comment:

```
 (1/1) TypeError

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::firstOrCreate() must be of the type array, int given, called in E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23
in Builder.php line 415
at Builder->firstOrCreate(4, array('coretable_id' => 4, 'description_itc' => 'EXTENSION_ITC_4'))in ForwardsCalls.php line 23
at Model->forwardCallTo(object(Builder), 'firstOrCreate', array(4, array('coretable_id' => 4, 'description_itc' => 'EXTENSION_ITC_4')))in Model.php line 1618
at Model->__call('firstOrCreate', array(4, array('coretable_id' => 4, 'description_itc' => 'EXTENSION_ITC_4')))in modelInteractions.php line 127
at modelInteractions->insertModel(array('Internal_key' => 'TESTKEY_4'), array('Internal_key' => 'TESTKEY_4', 'extensiontable_itc' => array('description_itc' => 'EXTENSION_ITC_4'), 'extensiontable_sysops' => array('description_sysops' => 'EXTENSION_SYSOPS_4')), array('extensiontable_itc', 'extensiontable_sysops'))in UserController.php line 100
at UserController->insertDataCreateNewItem(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(UserController), 'insertDataCreateNewItem'), array(object(Request)))in BoundMethod.php line 32
at BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()in Util.php line 36
at Util::unwrapIfClosure(object(Closure))in BoundMethod.php line 90
at BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(object(Application), array(object(UserController), 'insertDataCreateNewItem'), object(Closure))in BoundMethod.php line 34
at BoundMethod::call(object(Application), array(object(UserController), 'insertDataCreateNewItem'), array(), null)in Container.php line 590
at Container->call(array(object(UserController), 'insertDataCreateNewItem'), array())in RoutesRequests.php line 376
at Application->callControllerCallable(array(object(UserController), 'insertDataCreateNewItem'), array())in RoutesRequests.php line 342
at Application->callLumenController(object(UserController), 'insertDataCreateNewItem', array(true, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\UserController@insertDataCreateNewItem', 'middleware' => array('auth')), array()))in RoutesRequests.php line 316
at Application->callControllerAction(array(true, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\UserController@insertDataCreateNewItem', 'middleware' => array('auth')), array()))in RoutesRequests.php line 278
at Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array(true, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\UserController@insertDataCreateNewItem', 'middleware' => array('auth')), array()))in RoutesRequests.php line 258
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Authenticate.php line 36
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 105
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in RoutesRequests.php line 413
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array('App\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate'), object(Closure))in RoutesRequests.php line 259
at Application->handleFoundRoute(array(true, array('uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\UserController@insertDataCreateNewItem', 'middleware' => array('auth')), array()))in RoutesRequests.php line 165
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in CORS.php line 34
at CORS->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php line 105
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in RoutesRequests.php line 413
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array('App\\Http\\Middleware\\CORS'), object(Closure))in RoutesRequests.php line 171
at Application->dispatch(null)in RoutesRequests.php line 108
at Application->run()in index.php line 28
```

EDIT:
Question can be closed or deleted, the solution to the problem was somewhere else.

Comment: plz make sure the error come from here.

Comment: what is written on  `ForwardsCalls.php line 23`?

Comment: @sehdev forwardcalls is from the laravel/lumen framework.

Comment: @baryon123 post the whole error stack, let us know the error occurs.

Comment: @TsaiKoga edited in the full errorstack as requested.

Comment: @baryon123 can u post the line 100 in UserController.php, or the code of method `insertDataCreateNewItem`

Comment: What line of what file is `$lastInsert = $coretable->firstOrCreate($coretableKeyArray, $coretableInput);` (from your sample) from?

Comment: What is `modelInteractions->insertModel()`? You need to post that code.

Comment: @patricus, well, modelInteractions->insertModel() is exactly whats running here ^^ 
But if I escalated this post to the prototype of the function, I would have to post the context of its call as well, and this call isnt really relevant, is it? Because you can see all the components which are participating in the call to firstOrCreate() already, right?

Comment: @Jeto  its line 114 in "modelInteractions.php". Although the line might have changed slightly since this errormessage, since I commented some stuff and added other debugging lines and so on.

Comment: here is how its fixed for this user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154118/type-error-argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-database-eloquent-buildercreate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154118/type-error-argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-database-eloquent-buildercreate

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$lastInsert = $coretable->firstOrCreate((array)$coretableKeyArray, $coretableInput);
```

If that doesn't work, in case you've overloaded `firstOrCreate` make sure it doesn't do custom casts within it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing in a variable you can directly put it in the method.

Much cleaner and also readable.

```
$coretable->firstOrCreate([
 'Internal_key' => $coretableInput["Internal_key"]
], $coretableInput);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the error remains :/ Really dont understand why, I mean its obviously an array. Any other error would be more plausible than this one...^^

Comment: @baryon123 also try removing the array checking